# Chapter Links in Embedded Vimeo video

Tags: javascript, vimeo

Trying to get links to map to different points in an embedded Vimeo video, like chapter markers.

I'm using their API and it works for the first link I've got, but not the second.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/33cEe/2/) 15 Seconds link works fine, the 30 seconds link does nada.

I get it's probably to do with this line in the setupChapterLinks() function:

```
var links = container.querySelector('ul.chapterLinks'),
```

Which is only going to return the first item it finds (15 secs), and ignores the rest.

Any ideas what I'm not doing correctly?

Comment: But these aren't the chapters, these are just times.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue was that you weren't looping through the list of links you queried for. The result was that only the first link had event attached. Here's an example of how you would do it to all of them (a setupChapterLinks method to replace your current one):

```
function setupChapterLinks() {
    var links = container.querySelector('ul.chapterLinks'),
    seekLinks = links.querySelectorAll('.seek');
    for (var i = 0, length = seekLinks.length; i < length; i++) 
    {
        link = seekLinks[i];
        // Call seekTo when seek link clicked
        addEvent(link, 'click', function() {
            var seekVal = this.name;
            froogaloop.api('seekTo', seekVal);
        }, false);
    }

}
```